# Excel: Find matching email addresses in ALL columns

Tags: excel

I'm trying to clean up some email lists. I've got eight CSVs of email addresses. I'm trying to find email addresses that appear in ALL eight lists.

I've tried copying and pasting them into a single Excel document (a column for each list). But I am only able to compare TWO columns using methods like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "")`

so it doesn't tell me if there's a match in ALL columns (and technically that code tells me if there isn't a match). I can sort of figure it out by comparing two lists, then using those results to compare it to the third list, then use those results and compare it to the fourth list, and so on until I get through all eight lists. But

I've also tried using conditional formatting which formats duplicate values, but it again doesn't tell me if the match appears in ALL columns (it highlights if there's even one match).

Is there any way in Excel that I can indicate either with highlighting, or copy the value to a new column, any email addresses that appear in ALL columns?

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Make a copy of all the lists and remove duplicates, then use find() to test each column. AND() with the find() for all 8 will give true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just one formula:

```
SUM(IF(IFERROR(FIND(J3,A$3:H$12,1),0),1,0))>=8
```

See:

[image]

Just used names as you did not provide any data.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Let me make sure I understand the workflow...

1) You began by copying all the lists to columns A-H
2) You copied ALL lists to column J and used the "Remove Duplicates" function
3) You used the formula to determine True or False on column J.


I'm new to Excel and this project got dumped on me, I appreciate your help. Looking at your formula I understand what it's doing, but what does the part ",1),0),1,0)" do?

Comment: @Rothgarr that part ",1),0),1,0)" is in order: ,1) is the end of the find() which tells find to start at position 1, ,0) is the end of the iferror() which replaces an error with zero and ,1,0) is the end of the if() which replaces any numerical result of find() with 1. Do check out the help in Excel as the functions have their arguments expalined, try testing them by separating them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can do it easily with Pivot Tables. Instead of creating a column for each CSV file (like the left part of image above), just copy all of them in the same column, one CSV after each other (like column E in image). Then insert a Pivot Table:

1. Take field `Email` into Values section and rows Section
2. **Filter by values** using the number of CSV as criteria (3 in the image, 8 in your case because you got 8 CSV files)

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Results are the emails that appear in all CSV.

Of course, this will work only if each e-mail appears once in each CSV file. If there are duplicates, you'll need to deduplicate each CSV before creating the unique column